# LINQ queries are not yielding the expected result

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, .net-core

I have following data

[image]

I wanted to have all the records which contains **test** in its data. Below is my LINQ query which yields no result set. Please help me to rectify the query.

```
from recordings in Result where recordings.Contains("test") select recordings;
```

Comment: can you make fiddle of your issue https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

apparently you have an array of arrays so you need to specify the first inner field where you expect `"test"` to be found:

```
from recordings in Result where recordings[0].ToString().Contains("test") select recordings;
```

> although there are "test" words at different nodes

if test is not confined to the first position then you would need to use `Any` to test the entire inner array

```
from recordings in Result 
where recordings.Any( prop => prop.ToString().Contains("test")) select recordings;
```

Comment: This will likely throw a compile error, something like `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Contains'`, you'd need to do something like `recordings[0].ToString().Contains("test")`, or better yet, deserialize to a list of strongly typed objects and then do the `Contains` check on the property

Comment: This will only yield the result from the zeroth elements although there are "test" words at different nodes

Comment: @MindSwipe thank you for pointing this out. The `ToString( )` call should fix it

Comment: @DhruviParikh "This will only yield the result from the zeroth elements" `rescordings` is is an `object[ ]` so the select part makes sure that the entire array with its 4 objects of information is selected. and from the posted screenshot `"test"` is always at the first place in the inner array. unless of course `Result` is something else that I don't see in your post. In this case I don't have enough information to answer your question precisely enough...

Comment: `where recordings.Any(recording => recording.ToString().Contains("test"))`

Comment: @DhruviParikh "although there are "test" words at different nodes" you should add this piece of important information to your question